# PrintDocument just prints some part of my JPG file

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

I created an application that allows users to print multiple jpg files. So I send my print request directly, like this:

```
 if (existfile == true)
                {
                    PrinterSettings a=new PrinterSettings();
                    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                    IEnumerable<PaperSize> size = a.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>();
                    PaperSize a4 = size.First<PaperSize>(i => i.Kind == PaperKind.A4);
                    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                    pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = a4;
                    pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
                    pd.Print();
                }
```

And the print function :

```
   private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(CurrentAddress);
            Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
        }
```

But this code just prints some part of my image, not all of it .I want to print them `scale to fit`. How can I do that?

Comment: -Use a DrawImage overload that has two rectangles. One for source and the other for destination. The latter can be used to scale the image.

Comment: Point loc = new Point(0, 0);

Comment: @TaW could you please give me some more details ?

Comment: [Look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might fix the issue.

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.MarginBounds);
```

or

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.PageBounds);
```

or

```
ev.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\\My Folder\\MyFile.bmp"), ev.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds);
```

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: it Works but just one problem about 2 or 3 cm of my picture in below is missing

Comment: I use this one :e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.PageBounds);

Comment: Try with `MarginBounds` and see the results.

Comment: I used it but the picture is printed  small not scale to fit

Comment: Since I am not able to see the image printed. I would suggest you to see [PrintPageEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) and [PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can also try `e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds`